# Invalid transaction object the second time i insert

Tags: database, delphi

I have 3 function to insert a client. i am using transaction with mysql. I was watching other posts in this page which have the same exception, but my code is right. The problem is the second time i try to insert a client, i mean: i open the application in Delphi, an one client is inserted rightly. But other client give me an exception: Remote error: invalid transaction object.

Here is the code:

```
function TServerMethods1.insertarcliente( idlocalidad, DNI, cuit, cuil, cupodias: integer; descuento, cupocheques, cupopesos, cupochequestro: Double;
  domicilio, nombreyape, direccion, email: string ): boolean;
var
  uubicacion, upersona, ucliente: integer;
  tr: tdbxTransaction;
  exito: boolean;
begin
  SUCURSAL.Open;
  tr := SUCURSAL.BeginTransaction( );
  try
    begin
      with qipersona do
        begin
          Close;
          ParamByName( 'DNI' ).AsInteger := DNI;
          ParamByName( 'nombreyape' ).AsString := nombreyape;
          ParamByName( 'direccion' ).AsString := direccion;
          ParamByName( 'email' ).AsString := email;
          ExecSQL( );
          Free;
        end
    end
  except
    SUCURSAL.RollbackFreeAndNil( tr );
  end;
  try
    begin
      with qicliente do
        begin
          Close;
          ParamByName( 'idpersona' ).AsInteger := qucli.ExecSQL( );
          ParamByName( 'cuit' ).AsInteger := cuit;
          ParamByName( 'cuil' ).AsInteger := cuil;
          ParamByName( 'deuda' ).AsFloat := 0.00;
          ParamByName( 'cupodias' ).AsInteger := cupodias;
          ParamByName( 'cupocheques' ).AsFloat := cupocheques;
          ParamByName( 'cupopesos' ).AsFloat := cupopesos;
          ParamByName( 'cupochequestro' ).AsFloat := cupochequestro;
          ParamByName( 'descuento' ).AsFloat := descuento;
          ExecSQL( );
          Free;
          SUCURSAL.CommitFreeAndNil( tr );

          exito := True;
        end
    end
  except
    SUCURSAL.RollbackFreeAndNil( tr );
  end;
  Result := exito;
end;
```

---

```
function TServerMethods1.insertartelefonoscliente( numero, idtipotel: integer; descripciontel: string ): boolean;
var
  tr: tdbxTransaction;
  exito: boolean;
begin
  SUCURSAL.Open;
  if ( SUCURSAL.InTransaction = False )
  then
    tr := SUCURSAL.BeginTransaction( )
  else
    begin
      try
        begin
          with qtelefono do
            begin
              Close;
              ParamByName( 'numero' ).AsInteger := numero;
              ParamByName( 'idtipotel' ).AsInteger := idtipotel;
              ParamByName( 'descripcion' ).AsString := descripciontel;
              ExecSQL( );
              Free;
            end;
        end;
        // si no se pudo
      except
        begin
          SUCURSAL.RollbackFreeAndNil( tr );
          exito := False;
        end;
        try
          with telcli do
            begin
              Close;
              ParamByName( 'idc' ).AsInteger := qucliente.ExecSQL( );
              ParamByName( 'idt' ).AsInteger := qut.ExecSQL( );
              ExecSQL( );
              Free;
            end;
        except
          SUCURSAL.RollbackFreeAndNil( tr );
          exito := False;
        end;
        SUCURSAL.CommitFreeAndNil( tr );
      end;
      Result := exito;
    end;
end;
```

---

```
function TServerMethods1.insertarubicacionescliente( idlocalidad: integer; domicilio, descripcion: string ): boolean;
var
  tr: tdbxTransaction;
  exito: boolean;
begin
  SUCURSAL.Open;
  if ( SUCURSAL.InTransaction = False )
  then
    tr := SUCURSAL.BeginTransaction( )
  else
    begin
      try
        with qiubicacion do
          begin
            Close;
            ParamByName( 'idlocalidad' ).AsInteger := idlocalidad;
            ParamByName( 'domicilio' ).AsString := domicilio;
            ParamByName( 'descripcion' ).AsString := descripcion;
            ExecSQL( );
            Free;
          end;
        // si no se pudo
      except
        SUCURSAL.RollbackFreeAndNil( tr );
        exito := False;
      end;
      try
        with quper do
          begin
            Close;
            ParamByName( 'idp' ).AsInteger := qup.ExecSQL( );
            ParamByName( 'idu' ).AsInteger := quu.ExecSQL( );
            // ParamByName('descripcion').AsString:=descripcion;
            ExecSQL( );
            Free;
          end;
        SUCURSAL.CommitFreeAndNil( tr );
      except
        SUCURSAL.RollbackFreeAndNil( tr );
        exito := False;
      end;
      Result := exito;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here, but note that you free every query object such as `qipersona`. I don't see any instantiation...

Comment: What does the `FreeAndNil`versions of `Commit` and `Rollback` do, and what type is `SUCURSAL`?

Comment: You're swallowing exceptions, and then carrying on as if nothing had gone wrong. This is a recipe for disaster. You also haven't told us exactly which line of code is producing the error.

Comment: Well , i don't know wich is the line of code, because the client app runs. @kobik : i also don't see any instantiation, but i supose the objet sucursal (is tsqlconnection in clientdatamodule to datasnap server) may be instantiated.

Comment: @User, my point is that you destroy the object after the first time you call the method(s) (via `with qipersona do...Free`). so the object is already destroyed the second time you call that method, and since your `except` is not throwing any exceptions you might be getting this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You claim "my code is right"; but really it isn't. For example: In your first method you do the following:

- Start a transaction.
- Run the `qipersona` query

  - **[A]** If the there's an error running the query, you catch the exception and roll back the transaction.
- You then go on to run the next query as if nothing went wrong.

  - **[B1]** If it's successful, you commit the transaction.
  - **[B2]** If it fails, you rollback the transaction.

If **[A]** happens then **[B1]** and **[B2]** are both guaranteed to fail because you're trying to either commit or rollback a transaction ***that has already been rolled back!***

When **[B2]** fails you'll get an exception within an **except** block, and it escapes to an outer level handler.

To properly solve your problem, you need to stop hiding/swallowing exceptions so you can see the actual root cause of your problem.

Use the following structure:

```
StartTransaction
try
  RunQuery1
  RunQuery2
  ...
  CommitTransaction
except
  RollbackTransaction
  raise; //This is VERY IMPORTANT ... 
         //Don't swallow exceptions and you'll have
         //a much easier time finding your bugs.
end;
```

Comment: Although you are right with all this, but you did not catch the main point. After first successful execution of `qipersona` this instance is freed and that causes the exception on the second call -> invalid reference

Comment: @SirRufo Agreed. When the transaction handling and exception swallowing has been fixed, then OP will see the Access Violation error caused by destroying an object that shouldn't be destroyed there. However, if only the root cause is fixed then things will _seem to work_ until the first query fails due to a key violation or mismatched Db schema. From a pedagogical perspective I consider it important to apply the transaction and exceptions fixes first.

Comment: If you exec 2 querys: commit and rollback are one per transaction?, because i suppose those were one per query the transaction has. I think: what happen if you couldn't insert into persona, you won't be able to insert into cliente, so you need a rollback.

Comment: @user3780282 You should keep a deep look at how exceptions work

Comment: @user3780282 The whole point of a transaction is to ensure that for a group of queries: either all are successful, or if there are any errors then nothing is changed. So no matter how many queries in the group, you need 1 transaction. 1 Begin, 1 Commit if everything is successful, and 1 Rollback if anything goes wrong.

Comment: The structure in my answer is correct because: If there are no errors, then you get to `Commit` and everything is saved. But if there's an error, you immediately jump to the **except** block (_skipping over all the later queries_). Any earlier queries that were successful will be rolled back.

Comment: Finally to answer your question: "_what happen if you couldn't insert into persona, you won't be able to insert into cliente, so you need a rollback_". ***No it doesn't need its own rollback.*** Firstly, if it you couldn't insert, then nothing changed in the Db in any case. Secondly, the exception causes you to _skip over_ all other code until the **except** block. (So you wouldn't even try to insert into cliente.) _But if you swallow exceptions, then you lose this benefit - which is why swallowing exceptions is **wrong** ._